# Python Selenium can't access Tableau widget

Tags: python, selenium, widget, tableau-api, screen-scraping

I am trying to extract data from [this page](https://www.paho.org/data/index.php/en/?option=com_content&view=article&id=524:zika-weekly-en&Itemid=352) using Python Selenium. The table is rendered by Tableau. I would need to input some data and then use the download button.

Interestingly, I can't access the elements inside the table from Selenium. I tried looking by id, class or xpath. I keep getting the NoSuchElementException. However, these elements are rendered in HTML and I can see them with the inspect tool. Does anyone know why this is, and how I can make them visible to Selenium?

EDIT1: It's not a problem of loading time. I tried with time.sleep() and I am also interacting directly with the page.

Comment: Maybe the table didn't load? Try to add a delay using `time.sleep()` or [selenium WebDriverWait](https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-wait-for-page-to-load/)

Answer (score -1):

I can see your tables are inside iFrame. First go inside and then try to scrape table data.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@src,'zika_Weekly_Agg_tben')]")))

# COde here to scrape  data

driver.switch_to.default_content() # To come out of frame
```

You need to **Import**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. If you point your mouse immediately left to "As of Epidemiological Week" there is a little faucet that appears with the tool-tip "Click to Show All Values". For starters, I would need to click on that. I can't select in Selenium. Neither can I select other elements within the table.

Answer (score -1):

This was quite challenging since it has 2 `iframe` followed by shadow element. And does not stop here. When you switch to the `iframe` you don't have `iframe` reference available to access the shadow element. you Can refer below code. It manage to get the tableau chart heading.

```
# Get first iframe and switch to it
root1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@itemprop='articleBody']//iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(root1)

# Grab the shadow element 
shadow = driver.execute_script('return document')

# Get the iframe inside shadow element of first iframe
iframe2 = shadow.find_element_by_xpath("//body/iframe")

# switch to 2nd iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe2)
print("selected 2nd iframe")
shadow_doc2 = driver.execute_script('return document')
print("second iframe")
heading = shadow_doc2.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='tab-textRegion-content']/span//span[text()='Cases of Zika Virus Disease']/ancestor::div[2]").text
print(heading)
```

**Output** -

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I keep getting the StaleElementReferenceException for this line: iframe2 = shadow.find_element_by_xpath("//body/iframe"). Though I tried sleeping between every action. However, I see that it's a very complicated problem, and I think it's better to proceed manually.

Comment: I executed it again i did not get any such exception. Also I have `time.sleep(10)` before this code that may be the difference.

Comment: I didn't downvote you if you were wondering. I assumed the fault was on my side for not being able to reproduce your solution.

Comment: I know, you are not downvoter. In fact downvoter don't know that I had added the comment in regards of his action, if he has not looked back on this post. No worries. The downvoter downvoted on all 3 post of this thread.